# At the same time , just 1 Access token of 1 user account is accessed my app - Web API (OAuth2)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, oauth, oauth-2.0

I use Oauth2 to secure my web API. My problem is :

User "A" with account "A" login , access token "A" is granted . User "B" login with account "A" , access token "B" is granted. Then both access token "A","B" can access to my resources( same account "A" ).

How can I change this behavior so that when User "B" logs in, access token B is granted and access token "A" is expired.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The behavior --- whether issuing a new access token invalidates existing access tokens or not --- depends on OAuth 2.0 server implementations. The OAuth 2.0 specification ([RFC 6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749)) does not impose any restrictions on the behavior.

In fact, a certain OAuth 2.0 server implementation provides a feature to enable server administrators to configure the behavior. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39432659/1174054) for details.

Comment: Thank you , so how can i configure OAuth 2.0 server like :  "Single Access Token Per Subject " ?

Comment: First, you have to find an authorization server implementation that offers the feature. How to configure the feature varies depending on implementations. Note that the OAuth 2.0 specification does not mention anything about the behavior, so there is no standardized way.

Answer (score 0):

That's not going to be easy unless you want to change your web API to call back to the authorisation server and check whether a token is revoked. Also you'd have to change your auth server to revoke tokens based on your specific rules.

This goes against the grain of the Oauth2.0 spec in that the resource server (your web api) shouldn't have to make any calls back to the auth server when it has a valid token (i.e. signed correctly, not expired and with the right scopes).

I would suggest Oauth2.0 may not be the best solution in this instance.

Comment: Oh, RFC 7662 (OAuth 2.0 Token Introspection) is a specification that defines an API with which a resource server gets information about an access token from the authorization server which has issued the access token. The introspection API is supposed to be called  from within Web API implementations of a resource server.