# Can a user have two valid token at a time in oauth 2.0 for auth code grant type?

Tags: security, oauth, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

*I have simple question related to oauth token ,so my requirement is that user can have multiple scopes say A and B and he has generated token for it but later on he needs scope A and B both and his previous token is valid, So in that case

1. Should we update the scope for the existing token ?
2. Should we generate new token for new scope ?
3. Or should Generate multiple token for a single user ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to update the scope of the existing token and if your authorization server provides a mechanism for it, just do it. As a matter of fact, a certain authorization server implementation provides Web APIs to update scopes of existing access tokens (`/auth/token/update` API, `/auth/client/authorization/update` API).

Whether access tokens are modifiable or not depends on each authorization server implementation. For example, if the type of access token implementation is *"self-contained"* (e.g. like [JWT](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)), access tokens are not modifiable. On the other hand, if the type is *"random string"* (in this case, actual data are stored in the DB behind the authorization server), access tokens may be modifiable. See *"7.1. Access Token Representation"* in *"[Full-Scratch Implementor of OAuth and OpenID Connect Talks About Findings](https://medium.com/@darutk/full-scratch-implementor-of-oauth-and-openid-connect-talks-about-findings-55015f36d1c3)"* for details.

Some authorization server implementations issue multiple access tokens for one combination of a user and a client application, and other implementations issue only one access token for the combination. A certain authorization server implementation provides a configuration flag to enable you to select either of the behaviors like below. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39432659/1174054).

[image]

Which approach you should take depends on your use case. Look for an authorization server implementation which suits your use case best.

Answer (score 2):

OAuth2 access token is no modifiable, so you should get a new access token with a different set of scopes. Access tokens are generated for an application, not a user, but yes, there can be multiple access tokens authorized by a single user - the user authorizes the application to perform some operations (scopes) on his behalf.

Comment: fwiw: it would depend on the authorization server whether the previous token is still valid or not; the authorization server could have revoked it, if the access token type allows for that and such a policy is in effect